# Property function style conventions being affected by void*

Tags: c++, api, naming-conventions

I'm designing a public API in C++ and believe I'd like to retain C++ property-function style conventions that look like `int& Value()`, and `const int& Value() const` as opposed to get/set prefixes which return/assign by value because I feel the usage patterns are more concise and equally readable, while blending into existing C++ code very easily.

I need to allow the programmer to supply his own metadata. I've chosen to do so by exposing a `void*` property function. The problem is of course that having signatures like:

```
class foo {
  int& Value();
  const int& Value() const;
  void* Metadata()  
  void* const Metadata() const
};
```

...doesn't work because the following won't compile:

```
 void* ptr = ...;
 foo.Metadata() = ptr;
```

Because of this, I would have to use something like the following to make it work:

```
class foo {
  int& Value();
  const int& Value() const;
  void* GetMetadata();
  void SetMetadata(void* const data);
};
```

But that would render the styles inconsistent, so for now I've opted to stick with get/set prefixes throughout the entire API because of that, eg:

```
class foo {
  int GetValue() const;
  void SetValue(int value);
  void* GetMetadata() const;
  void SetMetadata(void* const data);
};
```

Of course, that doesn't fit the language convention I'd like to use.  Is there an alternative approach to this whole thing? If so, what is it? Am I stuck with get/set prefixes?

**Note:** I can't replace `void*` with templates for user meta-data as the API should be as stable as possible.

**Also**, I have already supplied a string get/set pair typed unsigned `char*` for user strings.

**UPDATE:**
After some careful (re)consideration I've opted to stick with get/set prefixes, I also won't use references for `void*` - if `void*` gives off a smell, `void*&` is pretty much a public landfill. As such, I've essentially opted for something similar to this:

```
typedef void* Any;

class foo {
  ...
  Any GetObject() const;
  void SetObject(Any);
  ...
};
```

Thanks for your input. :)

Comment: `void*` are gross. Consider using something else, like `boost::any`, or an abstract base class. What do you mean by meta-data, and what's the overall plan that you'd use it for?

Comment: I'll be using boost for various things in the implementation, but I don't want to expose anything boost-related in the public api.

Comment: Woops, also; meta-data is as its' name describes.. data about data.

Comment: So like a string? Anything you could wrap into a struct?

Comment: I already have a SetString function (not included above) specifically for string data (using unsigned char*).

Comment: Oh, as for the struct; that would add a needless layer of indirection which would amount to the same situation (only one layer deeper), the application is memory-bound even without meta-data, so management of the latter should be at a strict minimum since it's useful only to the user for the purposes of differentiating between instances of objects with real-world counterparts.  

A pointer to existing data is enough.

Answer (score 3):

Not that I'm sure this is the best design but, sticking to the question: If, for an attribute of type "int", you write:

```
int& Value(); //Used as setter
int Value()const; //Used as getter
```

do the same for an attribute of type "void*":

```
void*& Meta(); //Used as setter
void* Meta()const; //Used as getter
```

Comment: What part of the design don't you like?

Comment: Probably the part about it being a `void*`. Generally, that's a bit of code smell.

Comment: Indeed, and I agree, but sometimes you just have to make trade-offs (see added notes at the bottom of my question).

Answer (score 2):

You could have your `Metadata` functions return references to pointers:

```
class foo {
  int& Value();
  const int& Value() const;
  void*& Metadata()  
  const void* const & Metadata() const
};
```

Another alternative is to use overloading:

```
class foo{
  int Value() const;
  void Value(int);
  void* Metadata() const;
  void Metatdata(void*);
};
```

If you go this route, you could also make the setters return the old value for convenience.

Comment: I guess you must be using an old compiler that doesn't support that - it works fine here.

Comment: seems I deleted my comment after you saw it, heh. At any rate; I'm using MSVC 2008, and the api will be cross-platform (gcc). what were the function definitions of your first foo class? I copy-pasted yours as an exercise and failed to get it to compile.

Comment: though replacing void* with a typedef does get your first example to compile (excluding the redundant const in the second Metadata declaration, /W4).

Comment: Oops, I meant const void * const & - that's probably why it wouldn't compile. Or you may actually only want void * const & if you want the caller to be able to change the data pointed to